# Drawing static text on transparent window

Tags: c++, dialog, window, transparent, visual-c++

I am trying to display static text directly inside a game's window. I am writing a standard win32 dll that the game loads. The DLL creates a borderless and transparent dialog window that always lies on top of the game's window and fills the game's client area. The only problem is that when I make the dialog window transparent, the static text I put on the dialog becomes invisble too. Is there a way that I can make the dialog window transparent but not the text on it?

Comment: This question is too poorly documented.  One guess is that you use per-pixel alpha.  And discovered that GDI draws text with an alpha of 0.  The entire approach is questionable, good looking text requires aliasing and that doesn't work on a transparent background.